# Value Connected of type java.lang.String cannot be converted error to JSONObject error

Tags: java

so I'm new to android apps developement and currently trying to make an app which lets the user login with their info from the database.

I have followed tutorials from youtube and currently am stuck with this problem: Value Connected of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Login.php

```
<?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {

$email = $_POST['email']  ?? '';
$password = $_POST['password']  ?? '';

require_once 'connect.php';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users_table WHERE email='$email' ";

$response = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$result = array();
$result['login'] = array();

if ( mysqli_num_rows($response) === 1 ) {

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($response);

    if ( password_verify($password, $row['password']) ) {

        $index['name'] = $row['name'];
        $index['email'] = $row['email'];
        $index['id'] = $row['id'];

        array_push($result['login'], $index);

        $result['success'] = "1";
        $result['message'] = "success";
        echo json_encode($result);

        mysqli_close($conn);

    } else {

        $result['success'] = "0";
        $result['message'] = "error";
        echo json_encode($result);

        mysqli_close($conn);

    }?>
```

Login class

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.DefaultRetryPolicy;
import com.android.volley.NetworkError;
import com.android.volley.NoConnectionError;
import com.android.volley.ParseError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.ServerError;
import com.android.volley.TimeoutError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText email, password;
    private Button btn_login;

    private ProgressBar loading;
    private static String URL_LOGIN = "https://interntest1.000webhostapp.com/login.php";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


        loading = findViewById(R.id.loading);
        email = findViewById(R.id.email);
        password = findViewById(R.id.password);
        btn_login = findViewById(R.id.btn_login);

        btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String mEmail = email.getText().toString().trim();
                String mPass = password.getText().toString().trim();

                if (!mEmail.isEmpty() || !mPass.isEmpty()) {
                    Login(mEmail, mPass);
                } else {
                    email.setError("Please insert email");
                    password.setError("Please insert password");
                }
            }
        });



    }

    private void Login(final String email, final String password) {

        loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btn_login.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_LOGIN,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            String success = jsonObject.getString("success");
                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("login");

                            if (success.equals("1")) {

                                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                                    JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                    String name = object.getString("name").trim();
                                    String email = object.getString("email").trim();
                                    String id = object.getString("id").trim();


                                    loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                                }

                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            btn_login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Error " +e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        btn_login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Error " +error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("email",email);
                params.put("password",password);
                return params;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }
}
```

Comment: well maybe the String is not JSON?  But how would we know unless you give us the input?

Comment: The input for the login app is email and password , I have also uploaded the login.php code

Comment: By input, I mean the input to the problem that you are having, which I am **guessing** to be `JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);` - maybe my guess is bad?   How would I know as you do not give enough information.  If I am right, then what on earth is the value of `response`?